# Добавление значений из нескольких ячеек в одну ячейку

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть координаты для карты, в одном столбце широта, в другом долгота, и в третьем столбце ссылка на карту, в которой есть координаты. Как подставить в ссылку координаты широту и долготу в эту ссылку?

Пробовал просто в ссылку подставлять *=C5* , но это не работает.

Попробовал другим способом (может быть не совсем нормальным), то есть из нескольких колонок сложить ссылку, в одной колонке начало в другой конец и по середине вставить долготу и широту, но в этом случаи вылезает ошибка, что таким образом складывать можно только цифры.

Пример таблицы https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OzJIj4esFjT-Ng0KCgzvcvAXVdb6YxFpftbpXxid5eI/edit#gid=0

Думал сначала это будет просто, а оказалось нет. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов - Вам нужно почитать про [конкатенацию](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=ru)

Для примера, по первой строчке в Вашем файле, формула будет выглядеть так:

```
=CONCATENATE(C2,A2,",",B2,D2)
```

С учетом того, что в A2 - первая координата, в B2 -вторая, С2 - первая часть ссылки (до координат), в D2 - вторая часть ссылки(после координат).

Comment: Сергей, благодарю за ответ!